# Retrieve discarded column after using summarise

Tags: r

I am selecting the top 10 destinations of flights, and how many flights went there. To achieve this I needed to use summarise, which throws away everything that I didn't mention in the `group_by(..)`.

Later I need the column `origin`, but I no longer can retrieve this column, as it is discarded along with other columns. To keep the `origin` it seems that I would need to mention it in my `group_by(..)` but I don't want this, as my result would then be incorrect. How can I get the origin of these top 10 flights?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)

(newFlights<- flights %>% 
    group_by("Destination" = dest) %>% 
    summarise("AllFlights" = n()) %>% 
    arrange(desc(AllFlights)) %>% top_n(10))
```

Comment: what would you expect that origin is in each case? Since origin varies, you cannot assign a specific origin to a specific destination any more

Comment: I know, this is why I am asking for help on how I can keep the origin

Comment: again: what is your expected result? please provide it in your question

Comment: If you want to keep the old columns, why do you use summarise? You could also do the same thing in mutate. Sure you will get duplicated observations in you allflights column, but for you top_n selection you can simply filter that.

Comment: Sorry, missunderstood you. My task just asks what the top 10 destinations are, and how many flights were made to these. The the next task tells me to create a bar plot illustrating the number of flights from origin to top-ten destination. This is when the trouble comes, since I don't have origin anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to include `origin` in the call to `group_by()`.  [See documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/group_by):

```
newFlights <- as.data.frame(flights %>% 
  group_by(origin, dest)%>%
  summarize("AllFlights" = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(AllFlights))  %>%
  top_n(10)
)

head(newFlights, 10)
```

Giving you:

```
   origin dest AllFlights
1     JFK  LAX      11262
2     LGA  ATL      10263
3     LGA  ORD       8857
4     JFK  SFO       8204
5     LGA  CLT       6168
6     EWR  ORD       6100
7     JFK  BOS       5898
8     LGA  MIA       5781
9     JFK  MCO       5464
10    EWR  BOS       5327
```

Comment: you are grouping by origin, I think that gives a wrong result. The top destination is: ORD with 17283 flights to that destination

Comment: No wait, actually this might be correct. This is what I did at first, and discarded it, but I think you are right

Comment: I don't think the add=TRUE is necassary

Comment: Yep - you're right.  Did a bit more playing here and you just need to include "origin" in your call to `group_by()`.  The numbers are less for ORD (top destination when you don't include origin), since multiple origins go to that destination.... in other words, you have to consider here that origin and destination are linked in the table... hope that kind of makes sense.  EDITED the answer to reflect - that works for you too still, right?

Comment: add = TRUE has nothing to do about this solution. This would only make a difference if you already grouped your data frame in some way. Then the grouping would add up.